# How to disable Access 2007 Exclusivity Mode

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2007

Does anyone know how to do this? I get the message that I can't lock the database.

The network database won't open!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure everyone has:

Tools ==> Options ==> Advanced ==> Default Open mode = Shared